# I can't figure out why overwriting a file's contents with an array results in an empty file

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, io, printwriter

So I fixed the overwriting problem but now the issue is it eats the last line of the text file. Or I suppose It's just not writing it back to the file. Any ideas? The first method should change the password to a random one and the second one is just for counting the number of lines in the text file.

```
/**
 *  Method for resetting a password
 * Replaces current password with randomly generated one.
 * 
 *  @param testUserName is the username used for finding the password
 *       to replace
 */
public String resetPassword(String testUserName) throws IOException  {
    int fileLength = countLines();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Password.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String[] storeData = new String[fileLength];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pwNumber = (int)(rand.nextDouble() * 10000);
    String pwReset = "Password" + pwNumber;

    for (int i=0; i < fileLength; i ++) {
        storeData[i] = br.readLine();
    }
    fr.close();     

    for (int i=0; i < (fileLength-1); i += 4) {
        if (testUserName.equals(storeData[i])) {
            storeData[i+1] = pwReset;
        }   
    }
    PrintWriter reset = new PrintWriter("Password.txt");
    for (int i=0; i < fileLength; i ++) {
        reset.println(storeData[i]);
    }
    reset.close();
    return pwReset;
}

/**
 *  Method for counting number of lines in a file
 *  Used in conjuction with other methods for reading
 * specific lines of files.
 */
public int countLines() throws IOException {
   InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Password.txt"));
   try {
      byte[] c = new byte[1024];
      int count = 0;
      int readChars = 0;
      boolean empty = true;
      while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
         empty = false;
         for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
            if (c[i] == '\n')
               ++count;
        }       
      }
      return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
      is.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your countLines method

Comment: Is there any exceptions happening in between?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you countLines() method is re-reading the file to determine the number of lines at that moment.  This is not only very inefficient, but also the source of your bug.

```
PrintWriter reset = new PrintWriter("Password.txt");
// file is now truncated.
countLine() == 0
```

I suggest you count the number of lines once. ideally when you read it once.

---

You can improve it by

- reading the file once.
- not storing the file in memory so it doesn't matter how big it is.
- if it fails to write the file, the original is untouched.

.

```
public String resetPassword(String testUserName) throws IOException {
    File passwdFile = new File("Password.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(passwdFile));
    File tmpPasswdFile = new File("Password.txt.tmp");
    PrintWriter reset = new PrintWriter(tmpPasswdFile);
    String pwReset = null;
    try {
        boolean resetNextLine = false;
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            if (resetNextLine) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int pwNumber = (int) (rand.nextDouble() * 10000);
                pwReset = "Password" + pwNumber;
                reset.println(pwReset);
            } else {
                reset.println(line);
            }
            resetNextLine = testUserName.equals(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reset.close();
        br.close();
    }
    passwdFile.delete();
    tmpPasswdFile.renameTo(passwdFile);
    return pwReset;
}
```

Comment: and set that equal to a variable and then use that the rest of the time?

Comment: Or even better use a Collection such as ArrayList, then as you read your file line by line add them to the ArrayList.  Then at the end you have your line count and file contents.  You can then iterate over it using an Iterator.

Comment: So that got rid of the main issue. However i'm losing the last line in the text file.

Comment: Haven't covered ArrayList yet so I don't really want to go there. But thanks.

Comment: @Adam6806 If you look at the sample code, you don't need to store the data in memory at all. ;)

Comment: That's a little to far advanced for where I'm at. I can't use try and I was hoping to get a solution closer to my original design. It seems cheap to just copy someone's whole code in place of your own. This is already WAY above and beyond what I'm supposed to be doing so memory is not really a concern because it's only for testing.

Comment: @Adam6806 I suggest you try writing something your self from the ideas you get.  Hint: if you have a bug in your code, it usually a good idea to use the debugger to step through your code to see what it is really doing. ;)

Comment: You know I haven't been able to get that function to work properly and I was able to solve part of the problem. You'll have to excuse me but I'm just a CS1 student and the semester just started. I'm literally weeks ahead because I put in many many hours and this is the first question I've had to post so I think I'm doing pretty good.

Comment: @Adam6806 Even experienced developers forgot to use a debugger to debug code. In your IDE, its next to Run so use it if you can. Good luck in your course. You are doing well if this is your first year.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Well whatever it was it sorted itself out. EDIT: Nevermind it's still clipping the last value and I'm not sure why

Comment: @Adam6806 Another common mistake is not running the code you think you are. (When redeploying the code again "fixes" the problem)

Comment: @Adam6806 Imagine how good you will be if you do 50+ hours per week for 20 years :D

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I know right. Well I have to be on my game because I've already been asked to become the paid tutor for the dept when i'm done with CS2. So should I post what I've got so far?

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you see anything that could be causing me to lose the last line of the txt file

Comment: I would check the fileLength is correct. You can print out the value to see if its right. Again I would use a debugger to check why it is wrong (assuming it is)

Comment: @PeterLawrey the line counting was shorting me one for some reason so that's got it sorted. Thank you for your help so much!

Comment: @Adam6806 If you don't have an IDE, I suggest you use one. If you do, add the rbeakpoint to the start of your method by clicking on the line (usually to the left of the line) and press `Debug` instead of `Run` and you will be able to step through the program from the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

How does `countLines()` work ?

I'm a bit suspicious of this approach since you're using the result of this to iterate through your array. I would have thought it was perhaps more intuitive (and correct?) to iterate through the array using *its* length.

Comment: the password.txt file is a preexisting one that can change if people register. the countLine() counts the number of entries in the file

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded with the possibility of other threads modifying the contents of your file whilst you are processing the resetPassword?